# How to add Floweaver to a Bokeh/Panel server?

Tags: panel, bokeh, sankey-diagram

I want to plot a Sankey graph in a Bokeh/Panel server. I need the Sankey graph to be cyclic and the Sankey graph in holoviews only supports acyclic.

I found this library [Floweaver](https://sankeyview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that has the Sankey graph I need. I wonder if it's possible to embed this visual into a Bokeh/Panel server.

Answer (score 0):

So to get an actual interactive plot we would have to write a bokeh model specifically to perform the rendering of the JSON representation that floweaver outputs. However if you are okay with a static plot you could let floweaver do the rendering and then use the `widget.save_svg` to export the diagram to SVG. Once you've saved it you could then wrap the svg in an SVG panel pane, which can be composed with your other plots:

```
pn.pane.SVG('./sankey.svg')
```

It is probably also worth filing an issue with HoloViews to ask for support for cyclic Sankey diagrams.